# C# MVC5 Display Image slide show using ICollcetion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, icollection

Here I am trying to display images in slider. Because of foreach loop images are displaying one after the other like row wise. Without using foreach i am not able to get images. I don't know how to to bind Icollection and get photos data to view.
Model:

```
public partial class PressRelease                            
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    public PressRelease()             
    {                                                                      
        this.Links = new HashSet<Link>();            
        this.Photos = new HashSet<Photo>();            
    }

    public int pr_id { get; set; }
    public string pr_title { get; set; }
    public string pr_title2 { get; set; }
    public string pr_subtitle { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Link> Links { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()                                                           
{
    var pressReleases = _db.pressreleases
                                .Where(p => p.pr_approved)
                                .Include(p => p.Photos)
                                .Include(p => p.Links)
                                .OrderByDescending(p => p.pr_date)
                                .Take(10)
                                .ToList();
    return View(pressReleases);
}
```

View :

```
@model PressRoom.Models.PressRelease

@if (Model.Photos.Count > 0)
{
<div style="padding:10px">

        @foreach (var photos in Model.Photos)
        {            
            <div id="SlideshowImages">
                <img src="@Url.Content(@photos.photo_url)" style="width:100%;height:180px;" />

            </div>
         }
 }
```

Comment: You need to use JavaScript in order to get the Images to scroll through like a slideshow. The C# `foreach` will only allow you to get the images into the HTML.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: A search for "JavaScript Carousel Slideshow" will find you many of the current best practices. On Stack Overflow, we don't provide referrals to libraries as they change over time.

Comment: Thanks. I am using jquery to make image slider. But I am able to display the image slide show only when i am hard coding all images. I need to get the images which are already stored in DB.

Comment: Then you can update your question with that new information. Honestly, the way it stands now, it should be closed as "too broad". However, **only because there is no activity on your question so far** (answers or other comments) would it be appropriate to rework your question to include what you're having problems with now that you're using jQuery.

Comment: One hint I will give you is that with your `@foreach`, you're making multiple `<div id="SlideshowImages">`, and element IDs must be unique in HTML to be valid. You'd be better off using the HTML `class` instead of `id`.

Comment: Thanks it worked